# Apostrophe escaping in onclick - razor syntax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, escaping

So, I have this:

```
button value="Press me" name="btnLoad" onclick="calljsfunc(@Model.variable)"></button>
```

My data that is in the variable @Model.variable happens to have an apostrophe in it.  Let's say the data says "Bob's Place".  It gets encoded as "Bob\&#39\;s Place".  This causes problems with javascript because it sees that I have a semicolon before the closing parenthesis.  It gives me the error "Expected ')'".

I have looked all over the Interwebs, and have seen tons of solutions for how to fix this if I am sending a literal to the page.  But I can't find anything that tells how to deal with an apostrophe (or any other special character) in my data!

Can anyone please help?!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at encodeURIcomponent() function. There is also decodeURIcomponent() for revert.
Also you can encode you data as json.

Comment: I edited my question to show that my data is getting encoded with "ampersand hash 39 semicolon".  The JavaScript is still trying to compile and can't.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out how to escape the special characters.  I ended up using a Regex to find and suppress any special characters in the field in my server-side code.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, first of all, to provide the parameter via a `data-` attribute, rather than inline. That's relatively simple:

```
<button value="Press me" name="btnLoad" data-argument="@Html.AttributeEncode(Model.variable)" onclick="calljsfunc()"></button>
```

You would have to change `calljsfunc` to look at the `data-argument` attribute rather than the argument to the function. The value will not be encoded, so you'll be safe there.

```
var arg = this.getAttribute('data-argument'); // (for old browsers) OR
var arg = this.dataset.argument; // Modern browsers
```

However, if you want to do it this way, assuming `calljsfunc` takes a string, you'll have to do something like this:

```
<button value="Press me" name="btnLoad" onclick="calljsfunc('@Model.variable.Replace("'", "\\'")')"></button>
```

Note the tick marks before an after the variable; this is necessary because you are passing a string, I believe.